# PHP не может создать/изменить файл

Tags: php

Добрый день.
С чем может быть связано, что PHP не может создать/изменить файл.
Делаю один и тот же код у себя на компе-работает, а на сервере- нет.
Где настраиваются права доступа или что это может быть?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chmod 777 **имя папки**, где создаешь файл.

На сервере, разумеется, сделать это нужно.

Дома, наверное, виндоффс стоит. :)

Comment: Да. Спасибо.